# Slow performance with lots of images in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am working on a 3D environment in threejs and am running into some lagging/performance issues because I am loading too many images in my scene. I am loading about 300 500x500 .pngs (I know thats a lot) and rendering them all at once. Naturally it would seem that I would get much higher performance if didn't render all of the images in the scene at once, but rather, only when my character/camera were within a certain distance to an object that requires an image to be used in its material. My question is what method would be best to use?

1. Load all of the images and map them to materials that I save in an array. Then programmatically apply the correct materials to objects that I am close to from that array and apply default (inexpensive) materials to objects that I am far away from.
2. Use a relatively small maximum camera depth in association with fog to prevent the renderer from having to render all of the images at once.

My main goal is to create a system that allows for all of the images to be viewed when the character is near them while also being as inexpensive on the user's computer as possible.

Perhaps there is a better method then the two that I have suggested?
Thanks!

Comment: first of all, always try to use textures/images which size is a power of 2, so 512*512 in your case. 
Further, maybe combine your images into 1024*1024 images, so you have 75 images instead of 300 if this is possible in your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the power of 2 tip, I had no idea! What is the reasoning behind that?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent